# How to use logical operations in Outlook rules

Tags: email, outlook

I get loads of emails to "ABC" email-group which I am a member of.
How do I create a rule in Outlook which will mark all these emails read except those which are TO or CC directly to me?

So it should be like:
If (TO "ABC group") AND ( NOT ( (TO "me") OR (CC "me") ) ) - mark read

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

Create rule using Rules Wizard.
In Conditions step chose: Sent to "ABC"
In Actions step chose: Mark as read
In Exceptions step chose: With my name in TO or CC

This will create rule for all emails sent to "ABC" with exception when my email is in TO or CC fields.

Comment: This answer indicates the question is not appropriate for stackoverflow. Similar questions could be asked on http://superuser.com/tour